# Como checar se o número de resultados do mysql é vazio?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou com alguma dificuldade pra exibir uma mensagem quando a consulta não retorna resultados. Quando o `select` retorna 1 resultado `"if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)"` está mostrando corretamente, porém quando não retorna, não traz nada (`else`).

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
<div class="part3">
  <center><h2>Redefina a sua nova senha</h2></center>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['hash'])) {
      $hash = $_GET['hash'];

      $sql1 = "SELECT * from hr_link where link = '$hash' limit 1";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);
      while($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

        $hash2 = $reg['link'];
        $idusuario = $reg['idusuario'];
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    ?>
          <center>
            <form style="max-width: 450px" method="POST" name="formuser" action="cadastrok2.php" class="form-horizontal">
              <input type="password" name="txtnovasenha" placeholder="Nova Senha" class="txtfieldd" />
              <input type="password" name="txtrpt" placeholder="Confirme a nova senha" class="txtfieldd" />
              <input type="hidden" name="txtidusuario" value="<?php echo $idusuario ?>" />
              <br/>
              <center>
                <input type="submit" name="rec_key" value="Salvar" onclick="return validar() "  style="color: white; background: green; padding: 15px; font-size: 18px; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 20px; cursor: pointer;border: none"/>
              </center>        
            </form>
          </center>  
    <?php 
        } else { ?>
          <center>
            <br/>
              <form style="max-width: 450px" name="loginform" method="post" action="userauth.php?">
                <a href="?id=1" class="btn_modal3"><h5>Link expirou. Clique aqui para gerar novamente</h5></a>
                <br/>
                <center></center>
              </form>
          </center> 
 <?php 
       }
    }
  }else{ 
?>
     <center>
        <form style="max-width: 450px" name="loginform" method="post" action="userauth.php?">
          <a href="?id=1" class="btn_modal3"><h5>Link expirou. Clique aqui para gerar novamente</h5></a>
          <br/>
          <center>
          </center>
        </form>
      </center>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, o `num_rows` está dentro do `while`, o seu código não faz sentido. O que o código está fazendo é...

- Enquanto houver linhas (`while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))`):

  - Se houver linhas (`mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)`):

    - Exibe fomulário
  - Se não:

    - Exibe "Link expirou"

---

O `while` só vai funcionar se houver um registro (*ou mais*), ele nunca vai funcionar se houver zero registros. Logo, em situação normal, esse `if` nunca será utilizado, ele sempre será `> 0`. Então, para que o `if` seja chamado é preciso que o `while` seja executado, o `while` somente será executado quando houver uma linha (ou mais linhas).

---

Você pode simplesmente ignorar o `while`, afinal existe o `LIMIT 1`, isso iria resolver o problema:

```
<center><h2>Redefina a sua nova senha</h2></center>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['hash'])) {
    $hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['hash']);
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT link, idusuario from hr_link where link = '$hash' LIMIT 1");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        list($hash2, $idusuario) = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
        ?>
        <center>
            <form style="max-width: 450px" method="POST" name="formuser" action="cadastrok2.php"
                  class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="password" name="txtnovasenha" placeholder="Nova Senha" class="txtfieldd"/>
                <input type="password" name="txtrpt" placeholder="Confirme a nova senha" class="txtfieldd"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="txtidusuario" value="<?php echo $idusuario ?>"/>
                <br/>
                <center>
                    <input type="submit" name="rec_key" value="Salvar" onclick="return validar() "
                           style="color: white; background: green; padding: 15px; font-size: 18px; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 20px; cursor: pointer;border: none"/>
                </center>
            </form>
        </center>
        <?php
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<center>
    <br/>
    <form style="max-width: 450px" name="loginform" method="post" action="userauth.php?">
        <a href="?id=1" class="btn_modal3"><h5>Link expirou. Clique aqui para gerar novamente</h5></a>
        <br/>
        <center>
        </center>
    </form>
</center>
```

*Embora isso ainda esteja com outros problemas, isso irá funcionar como esperado.*

Comment: Muito obrigado,Inkeliz. Deu certo, me ajudou bastante.